# Problema com crawler multithreading usando o jsoup

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, http-status, jsoup

Olá,

Estou a desenvolver um crawler com multithreading, cada job (thread) trata de X sites para analisar determinados conteúdos com a lib jsoup. Os sites estão todos acessíveis. O problema é que o resultados final nunca é igual. Isto é, quando executo o crawler tanto me resolve 200 conteúdos como 180. 
Analisando os logs verifico que ando a receber 500 ou 400, na próxima execução já corre bem, volto a correr volta me a dar um resultado aleatório. 
Codigo jsoup (executado por cada thread)

```
try {
            Connection.Response resp = Jsoup.connect( url )
                    .userAgent( "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21" )
                    .timeout( 5000 )
                    .ignoreHttpErrors( true )
                    .execute( );
            doc = null;
            if( resp.statusCode( ) == 200 ) 
                doc = resp.parse( );
            else {
                log.info( "return url["+ url +"] statusCode == " + resp.statusCode( ) );
                return;
            }
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            log.error( "[Jsoup] get response url["+ url +"] exception = ", e );
            return;
        }
String title = doc.title( ); //get page title
        Elements links = doc.select( "img" ); //get all tag <img />
        for( Element imgItem : links ) {

            if( numImgsbyUrl != -1 ) 
                if( countImg == numImgsbyUrl ) break; 


            String title = getAttribute( hypeItem , "title" );

            log.debug( "[Tag Images] title["+titleImg+"] width["+width+"] height["+height+"] alt["+alt+"]" );
            if( !checkTerms( src, titleImg , width , height , alt ) )
                continue;


            resultsImg.add( new ImageSearchResult( title ) );


            if( numImgsbyUrl != -1 ) countImg++;

        }
        log.debug( "Number of results = [" + resultsImg.size( ) + "] to url[" + link + "]" );
```

Primeiro execução obtive 183 conteudos.
Segunda execução obtive 233 conteudos.
Terceira execução obtive 203 conteudos.
Tenho 5 threads a correr paralelamente 100 sites. Não sei se estou a ser bloqueado com tantos acessos do jsoup, Alguma ideia do que possa estar acontecer ?

```
Código da thread master:
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( NThreads );
CountDownLatch doneSignal;
...
// the SAX parser
            UserHandler userhandler = new UserHandler( );
            XMLReader myReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader( );
            myReader.setContentHandler( userhandler );
            myReader.parse( new InputSource(new URL( url ).openStream( ) ) );
            resultOpenSearch = userhandler.getItems( );
...
doneSignal = new CountDownLatch( resultOpenSearch.size( ) );

    List< Future< List< ContentsResult > > > submittedJobs = new ArrayList< >( );
    for( ItemXML item : resultOpenSearch ) { //Search information tag <img>
        Future< List< ContentsResult > > job = pool.submit( new CrawlerParser( doneSignal ) );
        submittedJobs.add( job );
    }

    try {
        isAllDone = doneSignal.await( timeout , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
        if ( !isAllDone ) 
            cleanUpThreads( submittedJobs );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e1 ) {
        cleanUpThreads( submittedJobs ); // take care, or cleanup
    }

    //get images result to search
    for( Future< List< ContentsResult > >  job : submittedJobs ) {
        try
            // before doing a get you may check if it is done
            if ( !isAllDone && !job.isDone( ) ) {
                // cancel job and continue with others
                job.cancel( true );
                continue;
            }
            List< ContentsResult > result = job.get( ); // wait for a processor to complete
            if( result != null && !result.isEmpty( ) ) {
                log.debug( "Resultado = " + result.size( ) );
                imageResults.addAll( result );
            }

        } catch (ExecutionException cause) {
            log.error( "ContentsResultsController", cause ); // exceptions occurred during execution, in any
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error( "ContentsResultsController", e ); // take care
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apenas com essas informações podemos supor qual o problema mas será difícil encontrar uma solução real para o que está enfrentando. Você pode fornecer [**um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável**](/help/mcve) do seu código?

Comment: Já editei acrescentado código do parser de html, código bastante simples. Acho que o codigo postado é o que faz o tratamento das threads e o parser é o que cada uma das threads executa

Comment: @user2989745 Tem várias coisas estranhas nesse código. Se você está usando um executor, porque usar esse `doneSignal` para fazer algum tipo de sincronização manual? Nada disso é preciso. no final, quando você faz `job.get()`, o `Future` aguarda a conclusão do job. Minha suspeita é que você colocou um timeout muito baixo e está cancelando os jobs muito cedo. Já que o acesso a sites pela rede costuma ser relativamente demorado, você então sempre vai pegar resultados aleatórios. Se puder, adicione as partes do código relevantes que não estão expostas acima e poderemos ajudar mais. Abraço!

Comment: Sim percebo de ser desnecessário o signal, o get é bloqueante, mas depois de alguma pesquisa não percebi se somente com o get conseguia receber todos os resultados de todas as threads. O timeout está a 100000, vou aumentar o timeout e já digo alguma coisa. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Entretanto retirei a logica do signal e o problema continua...

Comment: Editei com mais alguma código, ainda não consegui resolver o problema. Alguma ajuda ?